# How to convert single String column to multiple columns based on delimiter in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with a string column and I want to create multiple columns out of it.

Here is my input data and `pagename` is my string column

[image: 1]

I want to create multiple columns from it. The format of the string is the same - `col1:value1 col2:value2 col3:value3 ... colN:valueN` . In the output, I need multiple columns - `col1 to colN` with values as rows for each column. Here is the output -

[image: 2]

How can I do this in spark? Scala or Python both is fine for me. Below code creates the input dataframe -

```
scala> val df = spark.sql(s"""select 1 as id, "a:100 b:500 c:200" as pagename union select 2 as id, "a:101 b:501 c:201" as pagename """)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, pagename: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+-----------------+
|id |pagename         |
+---+-----------------+
|2  |a:101 b:501 c:201|
|1  |a:100 b:500 c:200|
+---+-----------------+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- pagename: string (nullable = false)
```

Note - The example shows only 3 columns here but in general I have more than 100 columns that I expect to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_to_map`, explode the resulting map and pivot:

```
val df2 = df.select(
    col("id"), 
    expr("explode(str_to_map(pagename, ' ', ':'))")
).groupBy("id").pivot("key").agg(first("value"))

df2.show
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|100|500|200|
|  2|101|501|201|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: can we convert the numbers in column `a,b,c` to any data type that we want on the fly? For instance, right now the output shows as `string`, but i might need those columns as `int` , `float` etc.

Comment: you can cast as needed in `agg`, e.g. `agg(first("value").cast("int"))`

Comment: is `str_to_map()` built in function?

Comment: available in SQL API but not in scala/python

Comment: If have multiple columns where I want to apply this function then what is the best way to get out the data? So for instance, if there is `pagename` column and `pagename1` column that both have such delimited data, then the number of output columns would be `id,a,b,c,a1,b1,c1` where `a1,b1,c1` are present in `pagename1` column. The number of rows would be same but columns should expand out

Answer (score 0):

So two options immediately come to mind

## Delimiters

You've got some obvious delimiters that you can split on. For this use the `split` function

```py
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    delimiter = ":"
    
    df = df.withColumn(
        "split_column", 
        F.split(F.col("pagename"), delimiter)
    )
    
    # "split_column" is now an array, so we need to pull items out the array
    df = df.withColumn(
        "a",
        F.col("split_column").getItem(0)
    )
```

Not ideal, as you'll still need to do some string manipulation to remove the whitespace and then do the int converter - but this is easily applied to multiple columns.

## Regex

As the format is pretty fixed, you can do the same thing with a regex.

```py
    import re
    
    regex_pattern = r"a\:() b\:() c\:()"
    match_groups = ["a", "b", "c"]
    
    for i in range(re.compile(regex_pattern).groups):
        df = df.withColumn(
            match_groups[i], 
            F.regexp_extract(F.col(pagename), regex_pattern, i + 1),
        )
```

CAVEAT: Check that Regex before you try and run anything (as I don't have an editor handy)

Comment: You've tagged `pyspark` so I've replied in Python, but the gist would be the same in Scala